# Unexpected HTTP 404 when running Request.Get() after a Post()

Tags: junit4, apache-httpclient-4.x, fluent

Is there a way to isolate HTTP connections to prevent the following behavior when using the Fluent API from apache httpclient?

I have some junit tests that use the Fluent API to do Gets and Posts.

When I run the junit tests *individually* I get the expected results. 

`Test1: Request.Post(https://host:port/xxx") HTTP 200 
Test2: Request.Get(https://host:port/yyy") HTTP 200`

When I run the junit tests as part of my test suite I get incorrect results.

`Test1: Request.Post(https://host:port/xxx") HTTP 200 
Test2: Request.Get(https://host:port/yyy") HTTP 404`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I used the HttpClient with an executor for each route.

```
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
Executor xxxExecutor = Executor.newInstance(httpClientBuilder.build());
Executor yyyExecutor = Executor.newInstance(httpClientBuilder.build());

xxxExecutor.execute(Request.Post(https://host:port/xxx"))...
yyyExecutor.execute(Request.Get(https://host:port/yyy"))...
```